# When refactoring my datasnap server cannot marshall if i moved a class to a different unit

Tags: json, delphi, refactoring, marshalling, datasnap

I have a datasnap server that I have to keep running or at least cannot update.
I would like to connect to it with a new Client.

All the code is the same but I refactored some code so now a class I use to connect to the server is in another unit.

The servermethods is a function that returns `TMyObject`. But in reality the server returns a marshalled object of type `Oldunit.TMyObject`. But this is not recognized by the client.

```
function TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject(JsonObj: TJSONObject): TObject;
var
  objType: string;
  ObjId: string;
  objFields: TJSONObject;
  Obj: TObject;
  rttiType : TRttiType;
  attr : TCustomAttribute;
  customizer : TJSONPopulationCustomizer;
  JsonPairID: TJSONPair;
  JsonPairType: TJSONPair;
  JsonPairFields: TJSONPair;
  JsonPairRefName: TJSONPair;
begin
  assert(JsonObj <> nil);
  assert(JsonObj.Count > 1);
  JsonPairID := JsonObj.Get(ID_NAME);
  if JsonPairID <> nil then
  begin
    JsonPairType := JsonObj.Get(TYPE_NAME);
    JsonPairFields := JsonObj.Get(FIELDS_NAME);
    Assert(JsonPairFields <> nil);
    Assert(JsonPairType <> nil);
    objType := JsonPairType.JsonValue.Value;

    ObjId := JsonPairID.JsonValue.Value;

    objFields := TJSONObject(JsonPairFields.JsonValue);

    Obj := ObjectInstance(FRTTICtx, objType); // returns nil, objtype is wrong
    if Obj = nil then
      raise EConversionError.Create(Format(SCannotCreateType, [objType]));
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming OldUnit.Pas to something different temporarily, deleting OldUnit.Dcu and then recompiling your client?  Does the server then work with the recompiled client?

Comment: I completely removed the unit, because it was now empty. And it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In My Servermethodsclient I changed the Type of my parameter. It works but it looks more like a quick fix to me and i wish i could automate it. If i had plenty of servermethods like this this would be tedious work, but for now it is only one method to authenticate on a server.

```
   pJSON := TJSONObject( FPW_GetServerInfoCommand.Parameters[2].Value.GetJSONValue(True));       
   pPair := pJSON.RemovePair('type');
   pPair.Free;
   pJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('type', 'NewUnit.TMyObject'));    

  Result := TMyObject(FUnMarshal.UnMarshal(FPW_GetServerInfoCommand.Parameters[2].Value.GetJSONValue(True)));
```